# Gmail in firefox showing time in UTC, but not in chromium

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, firefox, time, gmail

The time of emails in Gmail shows up in UTC in Firefox, but they are in Local time in Chromium. Calendar shows the local time.

How to fix this?

Comment: IMO you made the wrong fix when you changed Ubuntu to derive time from local. Windows is the outlier for using local time instead of UTC.  This is a vestige from pre-internet that they are overdue on fixing.  I'd suggest changing Ubuntu and Windows to derive time from UTC.

Comment: I entered the command `timedatectl set-local-rtc 0` but the issue is still there. Also previously the system clock was in RTC. Why would gmail use UTC anyway?

Comment: The issue is present only in firefox irrespective of whether system clock is set to UTC or RTC. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. The entry `privacy.resistFingerprinting => true` in `about:config`  forces every website to use UTC.

There is no other way to use local time zone in Gmail without being tracked by fingerprinting services, which is an annoying bug arising from extra security, because the user may want to resist fingerprinting, but still use local time.

This answer is based on https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1212634